# Xor implementation in Python gives incorrect prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, xor

I am implementing XOR in Python with Numpy. After having trained the weights on `[1,1,0]`,`[0,0,0]`,`[1,0,1]`,`[0,1,1]`, where the last element is the target, I'm getting roughly the same result for all inputs when I run the feed forward algorithm on the network, even though it is trained 50 000 times in random order. Where could the mistake be?

I have tried to see that the weights are being updated- and they are. I have also gone over my code to look for mistakes, but have not found any.

```
## Need to generalize it for n layers! it is generalized for n nodes in the 3 layers.
class nn:
    # input_nodes = 0
    # hidden_nodes = 0
    # output_nodes = 0

    def __init__(self, input_nodes, hidden_nodes, output_nodes):
        self.input_nodes = input_nodes # The number of features!
        self.hidden_nodes = hidden_nodes
        self.output_nodes = output_nodes

        self.weights_ih = np.random.randn(self.hidden_nodes,self.input_nodes )#2x2
        self.weights_ho = np.random.randn(self.output_nodes, self.hidden_nodes)#1x2
        self.bias_h = np.zeros([self.hidden_nodes, 1])#2x1
        self.bias_o = np.zeros([self.output_nodes, 1])#1x1
        self.learning_rate = 0.1

    def sigmoid(self,x):
        res = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
        return res

    def feedforward(self, input_sample):
        # Generating the hidden outputs: input_sample: 1x2                input_sample_T = np.asmatrix(input_sample).T
        input_sample_T = np.asmatrix(input_sample).T

        hidden = np.matrix(np.dot(self.weights_ih, input_sample_T))
        hidden = np.add(hidden,self.bias_h)
        sig = lambda t: self.sigmoid(t)
        hidden = sig(hidden)

        # Now, generate the output for the output layer:
        outputs = np.matrix(np.dot(self.weights_ho, hidden ))
        outputs = np.add(outputs,self.bias_o)
        sig = lambda t: self.sigmoid(t)
        outputs = sig(outputs)
        output_outputs = np.asmatrix(outputs)

        return hidden, output_outputs

    def train(self, input_sample, targets):
        targets = np.asmatrix(targets).T

        hidden, outputs =  self.feedforward(input_sample)

        # Calculate the errors from the output layer:
        # ERROR = Targets - ypred
        output_errors = np.subtract(targets,outputs)

        # Calculate gradient
        # gradient = outputs*(1 - outputs)
        desig = lambda t: self.desigmoid(t)
        gradients = desig(np.asmatrix(outputs))
        gradients = np.multiply(gradients, output_errors)
        gradients = np.multiply(gradients, self.learning_rate)

        # Calculate deltas
        hidden_T = hidden.T
        weight_deltas_ho = np.dot(gradients, hidden_T)

        # Adjust the weights by the deltas
        self.weights_ho = np.add(self.weights_ho,weight_deltas_ho)

        # Adjust the bias by it's deltas:
        self.bias_h = np.add(self.bias_o, gradients)        

        # Calculate the error from the hidden node:
        hidden_errors = np.dot(self.weights_ho.T,output_errors)

        # Calculate the gradient for the hidden layer:
        hidden_gradient = desig(np.asmatrix(hidden))
        hidden_gradient = np.multiply(hidden_gradient, hidden_errors)
        hidden_gradient = np.multiply(hidden_gradient, self.learning_rate)

        # Calculate change of weight for input -> hidden (deltas):
        input_sample_T = np.matrix(input_sample).T
        weight_ih_deltas = np.dot(hidden_gradient, input_sample_T.T)

        # Update the input -> Hidden weights:
        self.weights_ih = np.add(self.weights_ih, weight_ih_deltas)

        # Adjust the bias by it's deltas:
        self.bias_h = np.add(self.bias_h, hidden_gradient)



    def desigmoid(self, y):
        res = y.T*(1-y)
        return res



# ********* Main ***********
# The number of nodes in the neural net:
n1 = nn(2,2,1)
matrix_x = [[]] * 4
list_y = []
j=0
for row in df.iterrows():
    index, data = row
    data = data.tolist()
    y_train = [data.pop(2)]
    x_train = data
    matrix_x[j] = x_train
    list_y.append(y_train[0])
    j+=1
print(list_y)
print(matrix_x)

def randomize_train(x,y):
    for i in range(10000):
        rand = randint(0, 3)
        print(x[rand],y[rand])
        n1.train(x[rand], y[rand])
        print(i," ",end='')

# Running the program:
randomize_train(matrix_x, list_y)
```

```
h, o = n1.feedforward([1,1])
print(o)

h, o = n1.feedforward([0,1])
print(o) 

h, o = n1.feedforward([1,0])
print(o) 

h, o = n1.feedforward([0,0])
print(o)
```

```
Output: 

[[0.09657458]]
[[0.67883337]]
[[0.6458358]]
[[0.68269945]]
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of possible reasons. But generally I recommend to read the docu before using a library function.

- [`np.matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html): *It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays.*
- [`np.empty`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) gives you uninitialized memory(!); you want `np.zeros`
- Your weights are initialized all positive [0, 1], you probably want [-1, +1] or `np.random.randn`. Not sure if this actually prevents learning XOR from the gradient.
- Generally, I recommend to first implement only the feed-forward pass (no backprop) and learn XOR by trying random weights and biases, because that's much easier to implement and to learn from.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code with some of your input. I randomized the weights for instace, but I still cannot get it to output the correct predictions:(